# How to retrieve Cookies with System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, .net, http, cookies

I have this function:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("api/authenticate")]
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Authenticate(Auth a)
   {
       var cookies = Request.Headers.GetCookies() 
   }
```

After seeing a lot of posts on StackOverflow, I saw people trying to do this:

```
CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("session-id").FirstOrDefault();
```

But I don't see the FirstOrDefault method. When I run GetCookies, I got a string array with one element, and inside of it:

```
"{cookieKey=cookieValue; cookie2=cookie2}"
```

Should I convert this string to dictionary, or am I missing something on the API?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.current?view=netframework-4.8

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(CookieName);
```

Comment: This isn't System.Net, though

Answer (score 2):

Quite hack, but works

```
using System.Linq;

var cookies = Request.Headers
    .GetCookies()[0].Cookies
    .ToDictionary(cookie => cookie.Key, cookie=> cookie.Value);

return cookies["cookie-index"];
```

Comment: How the hell the API does not have anything for this?